# Oracle UDF problem - object passes to stored procedure but does insert NVARCHAR2,no insert for DECIMAL

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, odp.net, user-defined-types

We have a table as:

```
CREATE TABLE ESIPARIS.T_ORDER_LINE

(
  NO           NUMBER(18),
  ORDER_NO     NUMBER(18),
  ITEM_NO      NVARCHAR2(15),
  AMOUNT       NUMBER(18,3),
  INSERT_DATE  DATE,
  INSERT_USER  NVARCHAR2(20),
  UPDATE_DATE  DATE,
  UPDATE_USER  NVARCHAR2(20),
  FLEXFIELD_1  NVARCHAR2(100),
  FLEXFIELD_2  NVARCHAR2(100),
  FLEXFIELD_3  NVARCHAR2(100),
  FLEXFIELD_4  NVARCHAR2(100)
)
TABLESPACE DEVEL
PCTUSED    0
PCTFREE    10
INITRANS   1
MAXTRANS   255
STORAGE    (
            INITIAL          64K
            NEXT             1M
            MINEXTENTS       1
            MAXEXTENTS       UNLIMITED
            PCTINCREASE      0
            BUFFER_POOL      DEFAULT
           )
NOLOGGING 
NOCOMPRESS 
NOCACHE
NOPARALLEL
MONITORING;
```

And objects as:

```
DROP TYPE ESIPARIS.ORDER_LINE_ROW;

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE ESIPARIS.ORDER_LINE_ROW AS OBJECT
(
NO           NUMBER(18),
ORDER_NO     NUMBER(18),
ITEM_NO      NVARCHAR2(15),
AMOUNT       NUMBER(18,3),
INSERT_DATE  DATE,
INSERT_USER  NVARCHAR2(20),
UPDATE_DATE  DATE,
UPDATE_USER  NVARCHAR2(20),
FLEXFIELD_1  NVARCHAR2(100),
FLEXFIELD_2  NVARCHAR2(100),
FLEXFIELD_3  NVARCHAR2(100),
FLEXFIELD_4  NVARCHAR2(100)
)
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE ESIPARIS.ORDER_LINE_TABLE as table of ESIPARIS.ORDER_LINE_ROW;
/
```

And a stored procedure to handle objects sent by a .NET application to insert rows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ESIPARIS.pr_getorder_line (
   deneme   IN   order_line_table
)
IS
   err_code   NVARCHAR2 (500) := '';
   err_msg    NVARCHAR2 (500) := '';
BEGIN
   FOR i IN 1 .. deneme.COUNT
   LOOP
      INSERT INTO t_order_line
                  (NO, order_no, item_no,
                   amount, insert_date,
                   insert_user, update_date,
                   update_user, flexfield_1,
                   flexfield_2, flexfield_3,
                   flexfield_4
                  )
           VALUES (deneme (i).NO, deneme (i).order_no, nvl(deneme (i).item_no,'null geldi'),
                   nvl(deneme (i).amount,5363377869), deneme (i).insert_date,
                   deneme (i).insert_user, deneme (i).update_date,
                   deneme (i).update_user, deneme (i).flexfield_1,
                   deneme (i).flexfield_2, deneme (i).flexfield_3,
                   deneme (i).flexfield_4
                  );
   END LOOP;

   COMMIT;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      err_code := SQLCODE;
      err_msg := SUBSTR (SQLERRM, 1, 200);

      INSERT INTO esiparis.t_error_log
                  (event_date, event_object, MESSAGE
                  )
           VALUES (SYSDATE, err_code, err_msg
                  );
END;
/
```

We have created [UDT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User-defined_type) classes in .NET 4.0 using the Visual Studio 2010 and the [ODP.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Call_Interface#OCI-based_Libraries) plugin. We are at a point that values sent by a .NET application that are in NVARCHAR2 data type are inserted. Data in NUMBER or DATE data types cannot be inserted. Any ideas?

Comment: Hogan, thank you for formatting the code. I still do not know how to format it. Where is the doc about it  ?

Comment: *NUMBER or DATE data types cannot be inserted* -- Can you be more precise? Do you have a message error?

Comment: No we do not get any error messages. We have added the NVL statement to the field to be sure that NULL value comes there.

Comment: There is no error logged up neither in OracleDBMS nor in .net application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is probably due to type conversion from native .NET types (int, double, DateTime, etc.) in your calling C# code to the Oracle types (NUMBER, DATE) used to store the values in the database. Ensure the UDT classes are using Oracle types, not .NET types.

Also, if all you're doing is iterating over your collection to insert records, you should consider using Oracle's bulk binding capabilities as it'll be much more efficient. See http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/ado_net/BulkOperationsUsingOracleDataProviderForNETODPNET.aspx for a good example.

EDIT:
Per your commment: "We were looking for a direct SP example. This was good for using bind variables."

Either way, you need to be properly converting the types from .NET to Oracle. It sounds like you're doing exactly what's in this document:
http://download.oracle.com/docs/html/E15167_01/featUDTs.htm#CJAGFHBA

EDIT2:
Based on the code in the answer you posted yourself, it looks like there's a (slightly) better way to fix that.

You commented out some lines like this:

```
//[07.12.2010]ISMAILH : ISNULLS ARE COMMENTED OUT FOR PROPER WORKING!
// TODO : Add code to initialise the object
//this.m_AMOUNTIsNull = true;
```

The purpose of `m_AMOUNTIsNull` (or the property `AMOUNTIsNull` which uses that field) is to allow the code to differentiate an actual `m_AMOUNT` value that's set and one that's set because the default .NET value (0 for a decimal) is used.

That's why the value is checked before the UDT is populated with the `m_AMOUNT` value:

```
if ((AMOUNTIsNull == false)) {
    Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleUdt.SetValue(con, pUdt, "AMOUNT", this.AMOUNT);
```

When the UDT is fetched from the database, `AMOUNTIsNull` is set based on whether the database field is null:

```
this.AMOUNTIsNull = Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleUdt.IsDBNull(con, pUdt, "AMOUNT");
if ((AMOUNTIsNull == false)) {
    this.AMOUNT = ((decimal)(Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleUdt.GetValue(con, pUdt, "AMOUNT")));
}
```

But when you're using your .NET object and setting the `AMOUNT` property, `AMOUNTIsNull` doesn't get altered:

```
[OracleObjectMappingAttribute("AMOUNT")]
public decimal AMOUNT {
    get {
        return this.m_AMOUNT;
    }
    set {
        this.m_AMOUNT = value;
    }
}
```

If you change it so it is properly set (and undo the commented-out fix you've already made), you'll be better off since you're able to both store a value AND represent a null value as well:

```
[OracleObjectMappingAttribute("AMOUNT")]
public decimal AMOUNT {
    get {
        return this.m_AMOUNT;
    }
    set {
        this.AMOUNTIsNull = false;
        this.m_AMOUNT = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much checking the link. sorry for late reply, checking the generated classes with .net developer.

Comment: BQ, we had seen this page, it gave ideas but we were looking for a direct SP example. This was good for using bind variables.

Comment: It amazes that this is still not fixed in 2011, I found discussions about this bug in autogenerated code for UDT from 2009..

Answer (score 0):

After checking out the auto generated classes by the Oracle ODP.NET Visual Studio plugin,
our .NET developer has found out that it worked normally after commenting out some lines in the auto generated code, 4 lines starting after the line

"//[07.12.2010]ISMAILH : ISNULLS ARE COMMENTED OUT FOR PROPER WORKING!".

After that everything worked properly, but I wonder about the deeper reason for that. Why did the plugin generate these lines at the first place? :

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.1
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace ESiparis {
    using System;
    using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;
    using Oracle.DataAccess.Types;
    using System.Xml.Serialization;
    using System.Xml.Schema;

    public class ORDER_LINE_ROW : INullable, IOracleCustomType, IXmlSerializable,IDisposable {

        private bool m_IsNull;
        private decimal m_AMOUNT;
        private bool m_AMOUNTIsNull;
        private System.DateTime m_UPDATE_DATE;
        private bool m_UPDATE_DATEIsNull;
        private string m_FLEXFIELD_1;
        private System.DateTime m_INSERT_DATE;
        private bool m_INSERT_DATEIsNull;
        private string m_FLEXFIELD_3;
        private string m_UPDATE_USER;
        private string m_FLEXFIELD_2;
        private decimal m_ORDER_NO;
        private bool m_ORDER_NOIsNull;
        private string m_FLEXFIELD_4;
        private string m_INSERT_USER;
        private decimal m_NO;
        private bool m_NOIsNull;
        private string m_ITEM_NO;

        public ORDER_LINE_ROW() {
            //[07.12.2010]ISMAILH : ISNULLS ARE COMMENTED OUT FOR PROPER WORKING!
            // TODO : Add code to initialise the object
            //this.m_AMOUNTIsNull = true;
            //this.m_UPDATE_DATEIsNull = true;
            //this.m_INSERT_DATEIsNull = true;
            //this.m_ORDER_NOIsNull = true;
            Dispose(false);
            this.m_NOIsNull = true;
        }

        public ORDER_LINE_ROW(string str) {
            // TODO : Add code to initialise the object based on the given string
            Dispose(false);
        }

        public virtual bool IsNull {
            get {
                return this.m_IsNull;
            }
        }

        public static ORDER_LINE_ROW Null {
            get {
                ORDER_LINE_ROW obj = new ORDER_LINE_ROW();
                obj.m_IsNull = true;
                return obj;
            }
        }

        [OracleObjectMappingAttribute("AMOUNT")]
        public decimal AMOUNT {
            get {
                return this.m_AMOUNT;
            }
            set {
                this.m_AMOUNT = value;
            }
        }

        public bool AMOUNTIsNull {
            get {
                return this.m_AMOUNTIsNull;
            }
            set {
                this.m_AMOUNTIsNull = value;
            }
        }

        [OracleObjectMappingAttribute("UPDATE_DATE")]
        public System.DateTime UPDATE_DATE {
            get {
                return this.m_UPDATE_DATE;
            }
            set {
                this.m_UPDATE_DATE = value;
            }
        }

        public bool UPDATE_DATEIsNull {
            get {
                return this.m_UPDATE_DATEIsNull;
            }
            set {
                this.m_UPDATE_DATEIsNull = value;
            }
        }

        [OracleObjectMappingAttribute("FLEXFIELD_1")]
        public string FLEXFIELD_1 {
            get {
                return this.m_FLEXFIELD_1;
            }
            set {
                this.m_FLEXFIELD_1 = value;
            }
        }

        [OracleObjectMappingAttribute("INSERT_DATE")]
        public System.DateTime INSERT_DATE {
            get {
                return this.m_INSERT_DATE;
            }
            set {
                this.m_INSERT_DATE = value;
            }
        }

        public bool INSERT_DATEIsNull {
            get {
                return this.m_INSERT_DATEIsNull;
            }
            set {
                this.m_INSERT_DATEIsNull = value;
            }
        }

        [OracleObjectMappingAttribute("FLEXFIELD_3")]
        public string FLEXFIELD_3 {
            get {
                return this.m_FLEXFIELD_3;
            }
            set {
                this.m_FLEXFIELD_3 = value;
            }
        }

        [OracleObjectMappingAttribute("UPDATE_USER")]
        public string UPDATE_USER {
            get {
                return this.m_UPDATE_USER;
            }
            set {
                this.m_UPDATE_USER = value;
            }
        }

        [OracleObjectMappingAttribute("FLEXFIELD_2")]
        public string FLEXFIELD_2 {
            get {
                return this.m_FLEXFIELD_2;
            }
            set {
                this.m_FLEXFIELD_2 = value;
            }
        }

        [OracleObjectMappingAttribute("ORDER_NO")]
        public decimal ORDER_NO {
            get {
                return this.m_ORDER_NO;
            }
            set {
                this.m_ORDER_NO = value;
            }
        }

        public bool ORDER_NOIsNull {
            get {
                return this.m_ORDER_NOIsNull;
            }
            set {
                this.m_ORDER_NOIsNull = value;
            }
        }

        [OracleObjectMappingAttribute("FLEXFIELD_4")]
        public string FLEXFIELD_4 {
            get {
                return this.m_FLEXFIELD_4;
            }
            set {
                this.m_FLEXFIELD_4 = value;
            }
        }

        [OracleObjectMappingAttribute("INSERT_USER")]
        public string INSERT_USER {
            get {
                return this.m_INSERT_USER;
            }
            set {
                this.m_INSERT_USER = value;
            }
        }

        [OracleObjectMappingAttribute("NO")]
        public decimal NO {
            get {
                return this.m_NO;
            }
            set {
                this.m_NO = value;
            }
        }

        public bool NOIsNull {
            get {
                return this.m_NOIsNull;
            }
            set {
                this.m_NOIsNull = value;
            }
        }

        [OracleObjectMappingAttribute("ITEM_NO")]
        public string ITEM_NO {
            get {
                return this.m_ITEM_NO;
            }
            set {
                this.m_ITEM_NO = value;
            }
        }

        public virtual void FromCustomObject(Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection con, System.IntPtr pUdt) {
            if ((AMOUNTIsNull == false)) {
                Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleUdt.SetValue(con, pUdt, "AMOUNT", this.AMOUNT);
            }
            if ((UPDATE_DATEIsNull == false)) {
                Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleUdt.SetValue(con, pUdt, "UPDATE_DATE", this.UPDATE_DATE);
            }
            Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleUdt.SetValue(con, pUdt, "FLEXFIELD_1", this.FLEXFIELD_1);
            if ((INSERT_DATEIsNull == false)) {
                Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleUdt.SetValue(con, pUdt, "INSERT_DATE", this.INSERT_DATE);
            }
            Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleUdt.SetValue(con, pUdt, "FLEXFIELD_3", this.FLEXFIELD_3);
            Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleUdt.SetValue(con, pUdt, "UPDATE_USER", this.UPDATE_USER);
            Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleUdt.SetValue(con, pUdt, "FLEXFIELD_2", this.FLEXFIELD_2);
            if ((ORDER_NOIsNull == false)) {
                Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleUdt.SetValue(con, pUdt, "ORDER_NO", this.ORDER_NO);
            }
            Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleUdt.SetValue(con, pUdt, "FLEXFIELD_4", this.FLEXFIELD_4);
            Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleUdt.SetValue(con, pUdt, "INSERT_USER", this.INSERT_USER);
            if ((NOIsNull == false)) {
                Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleUdt.SetValue(con, pUdt, "NO", this.NO);
            }
            Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleUdt.SetValue(con, pUdt, "ITEM_NO", this.ITEM_NO);
        }

        public virtual void ToCustomObject(Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection con, System.IntPtr pUdt) {
            this.AMOUNTIsNull = Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleUdt.IsDBNull(con, pUdt, "AMOUNT");
            if ((AMOUNTIsNull == false)) {
                this.AMOUNT = ((decimal)(Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleUdt.GetValue(con, pUdt, "AMOUNT")));
            }
            this.UPDATE_DATEIsNull = Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleUdt.IsDBNull(con, pUdt, "UPDATE_DATE");
            if ((UPDATE_DATEIsNull == false)) {
                this.UPDATE_DATE = ((System.DateTime)(Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleUdt.GetValue(con, pUdt, "UPDATE_DATE")));
            }
            this.FLEXFIELD_1 = ((string)(Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleUdt.GetValue(con, pUdt, "FLEXFIELD_1")));
            this.INSERT_DATEIsNull = Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleUdt.IsDBNull(con, pUdt, "INSERT_DATE");
            if ((INSERT_DATEIsNull == false)) {
                this.INSERT_DATE = ((System.DateTime)(Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleUdt.GetValue(con, pUdt, "INSERT_DATE")));
            }
            this.FLEXFIELD_3 = ((string)(Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleUdt.GetValue(con, pUdt, "FLEXFIELD_3")));
            this.UPDATE_USER = ((string)(Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleUdt.GetValue(con, pUdt, "UPDATE_USER")));
            this.FLEXFIELD_2 = ((string)(Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleUdt.GetValue(con, pUdt, "FLEXFIELD_2")));
            this.ORDER_NOIsNull = Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleUdt.IsDBNull(con, pUdt, "ORDER_NO");
            if ((ORDER_NOIsNull == false)) {
                this.ORDER_NO = ((decimal)(Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleUdt.GetValue(con, pUdt, "ORDER_NO")));
            }
            this.FLEXFIELD_4 = ((string)(Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleUdt.GetValue(con, pUdt, "FLEXFIELD_4")));
            this.INSERT_USER = ((string)(Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleUdt.GetValue(con, pUdt, "INSERT_USER")));
            this.NOIsNull = Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleUdt.IsDBNull(con, pUdt, "NO");
            if ((NOIsNull == false)) {
                this.NO = ((decimal)(Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleUdt.GetValue(con, pUdt, "NO")));
            }
            this.ITEM_NO = ((string)(Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleUdt.GetValue(con, pUdt, "ITEM_NO")));
        }

        public virtual void ReadXml(System.Xml.XmlReader reader) {
            // TODO : Read Serialized Xml Data
        }

        public virtual void WriteXml(System.Xml.XmlWriter writer) {
            // TODO : Serialize object to xml data
        }

        public virtual XmlSchema GetSchema() {
            // TODO : Implement GetSchema
            return null;
        }

        public override string ToString() {
            // TODO : Return a string that represents the current object
            return "";
        }

        public static ORDER_LINE_ROW Parse(string str) {
            // TODO : Add code needed to parse the string and get the object represented by the string
            return new ORDER_LINE_ROW();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        private void Dispose(bool p)
        {
            if (p == true)
            {
                GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
            }
        }
    }

    // Factory to create an object for the above class
    [OracleCustomTypeMappingAttribute("ESIPARIS.ORDER_LINE_ROW")]
    public class ORDER_LINE_ROWFactory : IOracleCustomTypeFactory ,IDisposable {

        public virtual IOracleCustomType CreateObject() {
            ORDER_LINE_ROW obj = new ORDER_LINE_ROW();
            return obj;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: See the edit to my answer as to why the fix you made here is working.